# how to load atlas using base64 in phaser3?

Tags: phaser-framework

I am making a phaser3 playable ad and require to put images and other assets in a single HTML file. I can load the images using textures.addBase64 but how can I load atlas using base64.
Also if you could tell me how to put JSON in the HTML file so that I can refer to it while loading the atlas.
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Untested personally but take a look at [this solution](https://phaser.discourse.group/t/facebook-playable-ads-how-to-load-texture-atlas/6208/2)

```
 private loadBase64Atlas(key: string, data: string, json: object): void {
    const imageElement = new Image();
    imageElement.onload = () => {
        this.scene.textures.addAtlas(key, imageElement, json);
        this.onAssetLoaded();
    };

    const spriteBlob = this.base64ToBlob(data.split(',')[1], 'image/png');
    imageElement.src = URL.createObjectURL(spriteBlob);
}
```

Adapt as needed if you're not using TypeScript. Here's the [base64ToBlog implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16245768/941770)

The JSON object can be just bounced back and forth from and to base64 if you had the need to embed it in base64 aswell:

```
// get the base64 string to embed in the ad and physically store it
const atlasJSON64 = btoa(JSON.stringify(atlasJSON)); 
[...]
const objectatlasJSON64 = JSON.parse(atob(atlasJSON64));
```